# How to run server-side code AFTER page render & sending

Tags: asp.net, iis, browser, rendering

i hope you guys can help with this :)

I need to do stuff after my page is rendered in the browser. In detail, i need to send email/sms and other non-browser related stuff, but the operation takes time, and i dont want my visitors waiting 5-8s for the success message.

I have tried putting the "After Rendering Code" in the **page Unload event**. That seems to work - but only on localhost. It does not work on our production server.

So i figgured, maybe this is some **IIS setting?** I've also read that it's up to the browser, if it will show th epage after rendering is complete - or wait for the whole package to end.

So i tried to end the package with **Response.end** before my "A-R-C", but that just killed it.

Do you guys have any explanations or theorys on how to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ThreadPool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.aspx) threads may help you implementing this functionality.

Comment: What are the disadvatanges/advantages for using ThreadPool over MSMQ?

Comment: You're welcome! I've never heard of MSMQ before, so I can't tell you anything about disadvatanges/advantages. Someone else might help you much better with this.

Comment: I've added to my answer - in most cases Threadpool will work for simple solutions unless you need an industrial solution.

Answer (score 0):

You might look at asynchronously decoupling the Email / SMSing from the page entirely, e.g. by using a MSMQ Queue. This way you will also be able to handle the Emails / SMS in a more robust manner, e.g. retry in 10 mins if the SMTP server is down or the SMS gateway is busy.

Edit : Re : MSMQ vs Thread / Threadpool - Using a new worker thread should also work fine in most cases, however, for high end scalability you might consider MSMQ or similar.

Have a look at this SO post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1962948/when-asp-net-terminates-background-threads)

Threadpool (or Thread)
- Quicker and easier to implement
- Unsent SMS's / messages will be lost if the App Pool is recycled
- Will compete for threads  (recommend using a custom Threadpool)

MSMQ
- More work needed - will need to create a new listener process (e.g. use WCF) to process messages
- May be difficult to host unless you have control over the server
- Can be transactional and persistent - i.e. unsent messages won't be lost even if your App Pool is recycled or server reboots.
- Can exercise more control over throughput -throttling and delayed delivery - e.g. send SMS's after hours when it is cheaper

Comment: Ah, thanks for the additional information nonnb. I believe Threadpool is the the path to go for me, but your answer might be helpful to others :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new Thread and call your method on that Thread.