# How to call another controller action async?

Tags: c#, email, asp.net-mvc-3, asynchronous, actionmailer

I am using ActionMailer.net to send emails from my MVC website, the problem is that sending an email some times takes few seconds, and this delay my ajax calls.

I tried to use `DeliverAsync()` but the same delay is still there, I call the ActionMailer controller action like this:

```
new EmailController().EntryEmail(CurrentUser, CurrentUser, postText).DeliverAsync();
```

So my question is, is there a way to call the same Action but in another thread or async.

Notes:
I tried to make the ActionMailer controller inherits from `AsyncController` but couldn't because it is already inheriting from another class.

Also for reference I asked this question before: [Is it fine to send email from another thread like this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6514887/is-it-fine-to-send-email-from-another-thread-like-this)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not create a new base class that inherits from AsyncController?

For a simple fire and forget you can use `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem`.

Personally, I prefer to queue emails and have a separate background thread process the queue. This can be as simple as an "Email" table in a database and a `System.Threading.Timer`

Comment: ActionMailer.net is not my own classes to make them inherit from another base classes