# Run method asynchronously in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a webpage with a button that generates some files to a server path. (It takes somewhere from 5 to 20 minutes). I want to create an async task that will continue executing even after the user closes the browser. Is it possible to do this with asp.net 4 and C#?

Comment: More questions like this - http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=asp.net+long+running+task

Comment: Is this the same question as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/57845/backgroundworker-thread-in-asp-net

Answer (score 2):

You do not control the thread pool in an asp.net application. You cannot even guarantee that a request will be completed on the same thread that it started with. Creating threads uses the same application pool that the web server uses, and you can use up all the request threads leaving your web server unavailable to process requests.

You should implement a windows service that hosts a WCF service that you can call from within your web application. In the service you can then fire off a thread to process the long running process. At the end of that process you can then update a status flag (e.g from *Processing* to *Complete*) that the user can view to determine if the files are done processing.

I would recommend using [Topshelf](http://topshelf-project.com/documentation/getting-started/) to implement your windows service, it will save you much headache.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it is recommended that you not do this.  Instead, the recommended way is to create a service (e.g. a windows service) that performs your processing asynchronously.  In your web application, you create methods that starts the process, and another method that polls the service to determine if processing has completed.

There are a number of reasons for this, but one of the biggest is that the default and recommended configuration for webservers allows the server to kill long-running requests.

Comment: Can you give me some example oh how to do this? or link to a valid tutorial.

Comment: Create an interface in your web solution that contains the methods you want to expose from your web service.  Follow the tutorial [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3990/Simple-Windows-Service-Sample) here to create the web service, implementing the interface.  Add [web] service endpoints to your web application that pass through to the windows service.  I'm glossing over a lot; this will require a fair amount of work, but there are plenty of tutorials for how to do it out there, that's how I learned the first time.

Answer (score 0):

Or that I didn't understand what you want to do, or that you don't need to do a thing.

After the request was sent, the request process continues no matter if the user browser was closed or not. You don't need to do a thing

Fabulous nature of stateless WEB applications...

Comment: Nice. but how to make a page not to wait if a user wants to perform other actions on a page.

Comment: @user194076. ajax requests. google _"ajax tutorial"_ if it's new to you.

Answer (score 0):

you have to create a thread that does the long running task

have a look at the below:

http://kiranpatils.wordpress.com/2010/01/01/performing-a-long-running-task-with-asp-net/

Anyway what ever you start on the server it will continue running even if the user close the browser(until you recycle the app-pool or restart the web server).

Comment: That article is 9 years old, and does not apply to current ASP.NET development standards.

Comment: No it does not, but the development advice is bad. Much has been learned since then.

Comment: The way to do long running task under asp.net is by using Threads. The link is juts an idea on how to do it but the main point is I was suggesting to use a thread even if it is not a best practice starting new thread in ASP.net. Anyway I have changed the link that shows a similar solution

Answer (score 0):

Creating new thread / using thread pool is the easiest approach to create run away tasks.

Note that there is no guarantees that process will stay alive for duration of a long task - so be prepared to handle partial completion and manual restarts. I.e. AppPoll recycle due to config change.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to put your task on the ThreadPool. The thread pool threads will stay alive even after the web page has completed rendering. The code would look like the following:

```
/* Beginning Method */
object someData = new object();
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(ProcessAsync), someData);
/* Ending Method */

static void ProcessAsync(Object stateInfo) 
{
    string dataToString = stateInfo.ToString();
}
```