# How to make sure the server is handling the processing instead of the client when working on ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, client-server

I'm having an issue with this, the user can go to a page, click a button to start any given process, usually involving inserting or updating data on a database, which could take a bit of time, but if the user leaves the page the process halts and doesn't finish as it should. All the code is in code behind, as I understand that should be handled by the server instead of the client. So my question is, what would I have to do to ensure that if the user logs on the website, starts a process and leaves the website altogether the process will still complete as it should?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9792354/run-method-asynchronously-in-asp-net

Comment: This question is way too general.  Please elaborate on what exact procedure is partially completing, and include source code for the atomic (i.e. shouldn't be split apart) operation.

Comment: If I understand what you are talking about... Well you should not worry about closing the browser. When request (on button click) is send to server the process on server will do its job even if browser is closed. If you need to check server process result just save some status to database or file.