# Is it okay to use a simple backgroundworker in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want my ASP.NET application to send an email using a backgroundworker.  I don't want the user to have to wait while the email code us being processed.  Is it acceptable to use a backgroundworker in my controller to accomplish this task ?  What downside can I expect ?

Comment: possible dublicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13165965/using-a-background-worker-in-asp-net-with-ajax

Comment: "[The Dangers of Implementing Recurring Background Tasks In ASP.NET](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/16/the-dangers-of-implementing-recurring-background-tasks-in-asp-net.aspx/)" by Phil Haack