# How To Use BackgroundWorker in In ASP.NET WebForms

Tags: asp.net, sql, multithreading, webforms

In ASP.NET WebForms

How to run sql command in background and still play with controls and user interface does not freeze until result for command return ...I read about BackgroundWorker in Windows Application ..how to use it in asp.net webForms..

Comment: @Fred .. i am searching how to implement in asp.net ..web application ..not in windows application .

Comment: It is tagged as ASP.NET here is another http://stackoverflow.com/questions/57845/backgroundworker-thread-in-asp-net?rq=1 SO already has many examples

Answer (score 0):

just type in the code you want to run in the background inside the DoWork() and call runworkerasync()

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    //type the instruction here you want to run
}

private void btnStartBgWoker_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Run the background code
    backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For sql command in background you can use UpdatePanel to run code asynchronously.
ASPX-page markup:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="sm" runat="server" />
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upPanel" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="btnShow" runat="server" Text="Show me text later" OnClick="btnShow_Click" />
        <p id="ptext" runat="server"></p>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

And in code-behind file:

```
protected void btnShow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
    ptext.InnerText = "5 seconds past";
}
```